# Infinite Scroll with Firebase 9 in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm trying to implement Infinite Scroll with Firebase 9 in React Native, for a comments component.

I have a collection called **dailyTips**, which contains multiple documents, and for each document I'm keeping the comments in an array called **comments**.

This is how I fetch all comments for a document:

```
const [allComments, setAllComments] = useState([])

const getComments = async () => {
    try {
        setIsLoaded(false)

        const docRef = doc(db, "dailyTips", id);

        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(docRef, (snapshot) => {
          setAllComments(snapshot?.data().comments)
          setIsLoaded(true)
        })

        return unsubscribe;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      getComments()
  }, [])
```

This is what **allComments** state variable contains after fetching the comments for a specific document:

```
{
 "comment": "Yep", 
 "name": "Testing Account", 
 "time": "", 
 "user": "userIdGeneratedByFirebase"
}, 
{
 "comment": "Test comment", 
 "name": "Alex", 
 "time": "", 
 "user": "userIdGeneratedByFirebase"
},
...
```

And this is how I display each comment on the Document Details screen (I'm using map from lodash):

```
{map(!allComments ? allComments : allComments.sort((a, b) => b.time - a.time), (comment, i) => (
 <SingleComment comment={comment} matchId={id} key={i} />
))}
```

Is there a way to limit the query to a specific number in the **getComments()** function, to be able to get only the last 5 comments for example, at the beginning? And then, query the older 5 comments, show the ActivityIndicator while loading, and display them once loaded, to achieve the Infinite Scroll effect? I haven't found anything about querying inside **doc** on Firebase's documentation.

I think I also need to move to FlatList instead of map to be able to achieve this, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Does this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-native-firebase-cloud-firestore-implementing-infinite-scroll-lazy-loading-with-flatlist-a9e942cf66c6) help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-native-firebase-cloud-firestore-implementing-infinite-scroll-lazy-loading-with-flatlist-a9e942cf66c6#:%7E:text=module.exports%20%3D%20firebaseConfig%3B-,App.js,-//%20Imports%3A%20Dependencies%0Aimport) which discusses implementing lazy loading using  `Flatlist` in `react native. Hope this will help you to start your approach.

Comment: That is very outdated, and it doesn't contain a way to limit the query inside Firebase doc for a specific field, it actually limits the entire collection.

Comment: How about this [article1](https://dev.to/emmbyiringiro/build-infinity-scroll-with-firebase-and-react-native-expo-2dpb) & [article2](https://blog.jscrambler.com/implementing-infinite-scroll-with-react-query-and-flatlist-in-react-native/)?